# Auto Rotate Image Gallery with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, gallery

hope you all 'v been doing great

could anyone please help me with this

I am trying to rotate the image gallery automatically - currently its triggered by the links...

```
$('a.nextpic').click(function () {              
$('#slides').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);           
return false;
});
```

what I am trying is

```
function rotategal(param){
$('#slides').scrollTo(param.next().attr('href'), 500);
setTimeout(function() { rotategal(param); }, 500);
}
rotategal($('a.nextpic'));
```

but this runs it just once... I sure am missing some key here... any help?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your coding question but I've used a jQuery plugin called jCarousel with great success. The feature your looking for and many more are already available in jCarousel:

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Comment: thanks albeit I wanted something with least complex code... the reason why I did not use many available jeuqey image galleries... 3

Comment: I figured something out - dont know how this will perfectly work but - setTimeout(function() { rotategal(param.next()); }, 500); - works for now - albeit it ends at the last image, I need to reset it now and lets see how it progresses... will post an answer once I get it done!

Comment: :( no go - I tried - param.eq(parseInt(1)).attr('href') - but could not complete it - please help!